# Retrieve selected option text with angular, not only the value that contains the id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model

I was wondering what is the best way of retrieving the text that's between `<option>` and `</option>`, since the model assigned to the `<select>` only returns the id.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="videos.playlist">
    <option ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" value="@{{ playlist.id }}"
            ng-selected="savePlaylistName()">
        @{{ playlist.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

As said, and as it should be, `videos.playlist` contains the `playlist.id`, but how can I have the `playlist.name` also in a variable? The only thing I can think of, is working with `ng-selected` and process it then, but it get slightly more elaborate than what I was expecting and/or looking for. So, any ideas to easily achieve that?

Ideally, I would have something like `videos.playlist.id` and `videos.playlist.name`, because I need to have at hand the `id` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="videos.playlist" ng-options="playlist.id for playlist.name in playlists">
      <option value="">-- choose playlist --</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need both the `id` and the `name`

Comment: you can get name from playlist object once you have id.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-option with expression:

```
<select ng-model="videos.playlist" ng-options="playlist.name for playlist in playlists">
      <option value="">-- choose playlist --</option>
</select>
```

The playlist object is the selected object that would be bound to `video.playlist`.